# VBScript for Outlook, set Font's character spacing to Condensed

Tags: vba, vbscript, outlook

I am using VBScript to script a signature for outlook.
I did the settings for the fonts, here is my code:

```
objSelection.Font.Name = "Lucida Sans Unicode"
objSelection.Font.Color = RGB (168,153,110)
objSelection.Font.Size = 10
objSelection.Font.CharacterSpacing = "Condensed"
objSelection.TypeText "___________________________________________"
```

All works except for setting of the character's spacing to Condensed. What is the correct setting for the character spacing?

Answer (score 0):

Asssuming objSelection is a Word.Selection object (see [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/es-ar/magazine/2006.10.heyscriptingguy%28en-us%29.aspx) if it is not), the correct property to change the spacing is ... [Spacing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195646.aspx). But it does not accept literals, but size in points.